# asp.net project not loading inside the root of another project

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5, web-config

I have an admin tool that I want to run in the root of another project but the problem is that the admin project tries to read of the web config from the root project.

Is there a way to allow the allow the second web config, perhaps by means of a setting in the web config of the root project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best you can do is override in the sub-project's Web.config. Everything in the root Web.config will apply to anything under it, unless a different setting is added that overrides the root.

Comment: Hi, thanks, am sorry...am a bit of a novice, how do I override a sub-project's web config?

Comment: You just implement the same config section in sub projects web.config and then change what should be changed.